# Tk.winfo() returns wrong screensize / python 2.7.5 on Windows 8

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

Why does tk.winfo return a screensize of 1280 x 800 ?
I want to run at my native resolution  of 1920 x 1200
which I set in the control panel.
Can I change it somehow?
Thank you.
Python 2.7.5 running with Windows 8
Screen resolution set for 1920x1200 using the Control Panel

```
import Tkinter
CanW, CanH = 1920,1200
tk = Tkinter.Tk()
tk.geometry("%dx%d+0+0" % (1920, 1200))

w, h = tk.winfo_screenwidth(), tk.winfo_screenheight()

print 'winfo screensize = ', w, h         # Returns 1280 x 800

Tkinter.mainloop()
```

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce your problem, I've tried different screen resolutions and each one returns me the correct value for `winfo_screenwidth` and `winfo_screenheight`.

Comment: Try using `tk.update_idletasks()` after setting the geometry.